# Flash doesn't work right in Firefox. Won't respond to certain clicks

Tags: firefox, flash

I installed the Flash plugin in Firefox, and certain sites don't do what they should because certain things don't know they are being clicked on. Anything I can do about this? Will another plugin work better?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably affected by [LP #410407](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/410407)

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you are using the 32bit plugin on a 64bit system. If this is the case, then you need to edit the npviewer file.

Open it with the command below:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/lib/nspluginwrapper/i386/linux/npviewer
```

Then add the following line before the last line of that file:

```
export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1
```

The file content should look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
TARGET_OS=linux
TARGET_ARCH=i386
export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1
. /usr/lib/nspluginwrapper/noarch/npviewer
```

Save the file and restart the browser.

Alternatively, you could use the preview version of the 64bit plugin as already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably a problem of flash,try installing gnash or lightspark.

Gnash is in the repositories

for lightspark-

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/05/lightspark-open-source-flash-player.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu 64-bit, you might solve your problem by installing the (not yet officially finished) 64-bit version of Flash. Anyway, that's how I solved my problem of some mouseclicks not being recognized.

Download it from here:
http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplayer10/libflashplayer-10.0.45.2.linux-x86_64.so.tar.gz

Then copy libflashplayer.so to:
/home/"username"/.mozilla/plugins (replace "username" with your username)

If the folder plugins isn't there yet, you have to create it.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the Flash-Aid plugin. It will choose the flash version for your browser version. It worked for me even when adobe said that they will not support flash for FireFox anymore. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-aid/